# Adding a marker to a Google maps fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, mapfragment

I have added a map fragment to my application and added the following code to place a marker on the fragment.But I'm getting errors in the code snippet.I have included all relevant imports.

The errors are compile time and are as follows:

1.MapFragment cannot be resolved to a type.

2.GoogleMap cannot be resolved to a type.

3.LatLng cannot be resolved to a type.

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
                .title("Hello world"));
```

Anyone have any ideas where the error is in the snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should check two things first

1. Is the Google Play Service project or library added to your project ? If not, check this link http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
2. If you compile for android version < 11, you need to use supportFragmentManager instead of the normal FragmentManager :

   ```
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
   ```

In the last case, you also need to update the class used in your XML to `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

Comment: Google Api Android 4.2.2 is imported to my project which I think includes the play services?Also I have added relevant code to Proguard folder but still not recognising. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Google Api Android 4.2.2 is imported to my project" does not mean anything : you mean your project is compliant with Google API 17, which corresponds to Android 2.2.2. The real question is : what Android version is on your test device ? 
In any case, the Google Play Service must be imported. To do so, you need to import the Google Play services library in Eclipse, and from you main project, make a reference to it.